# Renaming menu properties in dash for multiple inputs/states during callback

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

So I have the following problem:
I have an app where I can upload my data as a csv file.
I want to make a graph which should be subdivided by a classifier column. I want the user to be able to pick what kind of graph he wants to plot from a selection and also which column does contain the classifier.

I have created a RadioItem object for picking the graph and a dropdown menu for selecting the classifier column and I would pass the chosen graph as the input and the chosen classifier as a state.

No the problem is, that the selected item from both, the RadioItem as well as the dropdown menu is called 'value'. So I would get something like this:

```
def RadioItems():
    return dcc.RadioItems(
    options=[
        {'label': 'lineplot', 'value': 'lineplot'},
        {'label': 'None', 'value' : 'None'}

    ],
    value='None',
    id='graph_selector')
def classifier_choice(df):
    '''
    called when data is uploaded
    '''
    columns=df.columns
    classifieroptions= [{'label' :k, 'value' :k} for k in columns]
    return dcc.Dropdown(
            #label='Classifier Column',
            id='classifier_choice',
            options=classifieroptions,
            placeholder='select the classifier column')
app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Table(id='output-data-upload'),
    RadioItems(),

    dcc.Graph(id='migration_data'),
    #hidden divs for storing data
    html.Div(id='shared_data', style={'display':'none'})
])
graph_options={'None':print(), 'lineplot':GD.lineplot}
@app.callback(Output('migration_data', 'figure'),
              [Input('graph_selector', 'value')],
              [State('classifier_choice', 'value')])


def get_value(value, value):
    return graph_options[value](df, value, testmode=True)
```

Despite me getting the error:
"AttributeError: 'Div' object has no attribute 'keys'"

this of course does not make any sense, since there is no way to differentiate between the two values.
Is there a way to rename the value attribute of a dropdown menu, or assign it's value to another variable in a way of:

```
classifier=classifier_choice.value()
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about the argument names: The callback decorator gets the attributes of the components and passes them as arguments to the function in the given order. You can name the arguments whatever you like.

```py
def get_value(selected_graph, selected_classifier):
    return graph_options[selected_graph](df, selected_classifier, testmode=True)
```

You'd propably have to return something compatible with the figure attribute of the Graph component. Despite that, in order for your graph_options' values to return function objects you need to get rid of the parenthesis after `print`.